# Verifying that Jenkins multi-branch pipeline is using reference repo

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

How can I verify that the multi-branch pipeline is using a reference repo? We have configured the reference repo in:

```
Git -> Additional Behaviours -> Path of the reference repo to use during clone
```

but the "Scan Multibranch Pipeline" is still very slow due to our large repo. Will this use the reference repo to look for Jenkinsfiles? Is there a way to increase logging for this so we can definitively see if the reference repo is being used?

Comment: Over 5 years of silence. Why haven't I given up on Jenkins yet?